# Why does not it work async pipe?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'trans',
  pure: false
})
export class RandomPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private  cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  transform(value:string):any {
    return new AsyncPipe(this.cdRef).transform(new Observable<string>(observer=>{
      observer.next('rand1');
      setTimeout(()=>{
        observer.next('rand@2');
      })
    }));
  }
}
```

It works only 'rand1' string - sync,
but  observer.next('rand@2');

not work - async. 
how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to achive it this way:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'someRand',
  pure: false
})
export class RandomPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private  cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  pipe: AsyncPipe;
  obs: Observable<string>;

  transform(value:string):any {
    if (!this.pipe) {
      this.pipe = new AsyncPipe(this.cdRef);
      this.obs = new Observable<string>(observer=>{
        observer.next('rand1');
        setTimeout(()=>{
          observer.next('rand@2');
        }, 500)
      });
    }

    return this.pipe.transform(this.obs);
  }
}
```

See also **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/fIibICNWF6Fs4np7yRLh?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `AsyncPipe` here

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'trans',
  pure: false
})
export class RandomPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private  cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  transform(value:string):any {
    return new Observable<string>(observer=>{
      observer.next('rand1');
      setTimeout(()=>{
        observer.next('rand@2');
      })
    }));
  }
}
```

and then use the async pipe like

```
{{someValue | trans | async }}
```

Comment: How not to write every time | async }} ?

Comment: By not using async calls. There is no way to go back from async to sync. Using the Async pipe inside the pipe doesn't buy you anything and there is also no way. What you can do is not using a pipe but instead calculate the transformed value in your components class and assign it to a property and then just bind to this property (without using a pipe)

Comment: So always have to use? | async?

Comment: Yes, that's the only way async results can be used in bindings.

Comment: the thing is that your example not working too, only 'rand1' print

Comment: I guess you should use `Observable.interval()` instead of `setTimeout()`. (similar to https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/merge.md)